# AFNetworking 2.5: How to retrieve info from php

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking-2, xcode7

I am a NOOB when it comes to using AFNetworking and I am running into some issues. 
I have a simple php script that echoes "hello world" and i would like to access the data for use in iOS (using Xcode-beta 7). I have imported the (AFNetowrking and UIKit+AFNetworking) files into my project as well as the .h file.

When I access the php script via my web browser, the response is printed but when using the Get method provided in the AFNetworking docs, i keep getting an error that says...

> 2015-07-10 12:22:46.553 TestPhp[2187:53179] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7ff99062b240 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff990718610 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myServer.example.com/connect.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myServer.example.com/connect.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

my php file called "connect" looks like this

```
<?php echo json_encode(@"Hello World"); ?>
```

I am calling the AFNetworking options in my viewDidLoad method in Xcode to print to the console. that method looks like this....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://ios.rcptfit.com/connect.php" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the connectivity of your device.

Comment: @FawadMasud I am using the installed ios6 simulater and the build is on ios8.4

Comment: "The request timed out" means what it says: the simulator timed out and can't connect to the server. Your AFNetworking code looks fine, except that `"hello there"` isn't valid JSON, so `responseObject` will be `nil`. (You may want to check `operation.responseString` instead.)